# Problem with creating smooth transitions using transform

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on web design, and I'm stuck trying to figure out why my code isn't working. Heres the part of code which I believe isn't working properly:

```
transition: transform 650ms cubic-bezier(0.54, -0.81, 0.57, 0.57);
```

And here's a code pen with the complete code, line 102/110:https://codepen.io/TrocaderoDrink/pen/oNvMBxp.
it appears that 'transform' isn't being recognized in my editor(vs code). If anyone could help me that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the problem that you facing here?

Comment: I'm trying to create a smooth animation for a button that opens a drop-down menu. When pressed the button is supposed to smoothly rotate forming an X, but instead, it snaps into position.

Comment: and now you fixed the issue inside your codepen making the question irrelevant since no one is able to see the issue.

Comment: I havent changed anything in the codepen, the issue I was facing is still there. Pressing the button in the upper right plays the broken animation of it snapping to -45deg. I left the problem in the codepen if others want to see the mistake I made and how I fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Replacing 'transform' with 'all' solved the issue.